# How often should I redeposit money in my blocked account?

Tags: germany

For creating a blocked account for studying in Germany, we deposit 11k euros, but afterwards when is the next time we should deposit money supposing we are enrolled in a university in Germany?

Comment: How long are you planning to study in Germany? After the initial year your blocked account would be extended every 12 months until the end of your studies https://www.mygermanuniversity.com/articles/Germany-Blocked-Account-Amount

Comment: Ah okay, thanks that answers @Traveller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning a comment into an answer:

After the initial year your blocked account would be extended every 12 months until the end of your studies.

As of May 2023, €11,208 (or €934 per month) is the minimum amount required by the German government. This amount is not set in stone, and has increased from €10 236 (equivalent to €850 per month) in 2019 to the amount set for 2023. German Blocked Account providers have their own regulations and fees related to opening and maintaining the blocked account.

Source: [German Blocked Account Amount: A Guide for International Students (2023)](https://www.mygermanuniversity.com/articles/Germany-Blocked-Account-Amount)